# How to add multiple CSS elements to a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to do this:

```
<div style="float: left;
            width: 59px;
            background: transparent url('http://download.com/47.jpg') no-repeat scroll -132px -1px;"
     class="cIconSmall">
</div>
```

and I'm thinking I should use this:

```
$("#YourElementID").css({
    float: "left",
    width: "59px",
    background: "transparent url('http://download.com/47.jpg') no-repeat scroll -132px -1px"
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the right syntax.  Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: The only thing wrong with the code you first posted is that instead of `$('#YourElementId')` , you needed to do `$('.YourClassName')` since the div has a Class and not an Id

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're thinking correctly. Using the `css(map)` method is the way to go.

```
$(".cIconSmall").css({
    float: "left", 
    width: "59px", 
    background: "transparent url('http://download.com/47.jpg') no-repeat scroll -132px -1px" 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

> A map of property-value pairs to set.

---

Might be nicer as a css class, though... then you can just write `$(".cIconSmall").addClass("icon47");` but there's a time for everything...

Comment: thanks, i was thinking to add a class, but my link will be different every time.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesnot work 
until i put float ,width,backroung around quotes

Comment: I had to do this for it to work.

`$('#selector').css({'property': 'val','property': 'val'});`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".yourClass").css({
    float: "left",
    width: "59px",
    background: "transparent url('http://download.com/47.jpg') no-repeat scroll -132px -1px"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that Andrew Lohr's comment in the accepted solution is for sure the only way I got this to work in my script: `$('#selector').css({'property': 'val','property': 'val'});` (and thanks Andrew).

Comment: Comments should be added as a comment, not an answer